# Some css styles work differently after upgrading to Chrome 60+

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```css
.tbodyBugHeight {
  height: 100%;
}
.tbodyBugHeight .tdBugHeight {
  height: 100%;
}
.tbodyBugHeight .tdBugHeight .firstBlock {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.tbodyBugHeight .secondBlock {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="tbodyBugHeight">
    <tr>
      <td class="tdBugHeight">
        <div class="firstBlock">This text is hidden in Chrome 60</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="secondBlock"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This code works fine (`.firstBlock` has `100px` height with y scroll) on Chrome(ium) 59, firefox etc but after update to Chrome 60, `height: 100%` (any percent height value from 0 to 100) doesnt work correct with `div height:100%; overflow-y: scroll;` in child.

[image: ch60bug]

Why it happends? Is this a chrome 60 bug? How to fix it?

Comment: A remark: In chrome 61 one currently gets the same result as you show for chrome 60.

Comment: did you post your issue to chomium ? i had same issue, i would star this issue

Comment: @TimTJeyJun chromium 60+ too like chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, my solution is: set height to div, like `height: 20px;`.
If the content is larger in height than the parent, the more it will stretch it in height.

Comment: My height is dynamically. I cant set static height :(

Comment: me too))

If at td the height is static and the content is greater then td is stretched along the height

Comment: Surprisingly, setting any non-percentage height to `.tdBugHeight` cell makes 100% height for the nested div work. And the actual height of `.tdBugHeight` is determined by the tallest cell in the `tr` regardless this value (it this value doesn't make `.tdBugHeight` itself the tallest one). So, actually, even values like `1px` help. Reminded me of this: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201306/height_in_percent_when_parent_has_min-height_and_no_height/

Comment: @MichałTurczyn he means that he **had** such a problem and his solution really works. I dont know why but it works. You should click "+" to his post instead "-" (if you click "-" of course)